# TSP on a unitary circle

Tags: traveling-salesman-problem

I am interested in knowing which is the expected length of a random path in a circle. That is, if there are $n$ random points located in the unitary circle $\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$, what is the expected length of the shortest path the connects all of them starting from the origin? In Wikipedia there are some results regarding the unitary square, but I have found nothing for the unitary circle. Thanks!

Comment: you mean the unit disc rather than the unit circle, don't you?

Comment: Do you know the Beardwood-Halton-Hammersley-theorem?

Comment: That theorem answers my question, thanks!